# Returning Data From 2 Tables and Filtering Out Information

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to Join 2 tables based on WorkCentres. In the one table the field is called LWorkCentre, in the other table it is called WorkCentre.

I have done a Full Outer Join to join these two tables. Then I want to return overtime hours based on the overtime work centres. So where the overtime WorkCentre is applicable then return the runtime hours otherwise return 0.

This is how I have written the view however, it isn't returning any values.
Please Help I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
dbo.PrjJobHierDet.JobEstimate AS CONTRACT,
dbo.PrjContMaster.ContractDesc1 AS CONTRACT_NAME,
dbo.WipJobPost.TrnDate AS DATE,
dbo.WipJobPost.LWorkCentre AS WORKCENTRE,
dbo.WipJobPost.LWorkCentreDesc AS WORKCENTRE_DESC,
dbo.WipJobPost.Hierarchy1 AS SECTION,
dbo.WipJobPost.Hierarchy2 AS HIER,
dbo.WipJobPost.LEmployee AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
dbo.BomEmployee.Name AS EMPLOYEE_NAME,
dbo.WipJobPost.LRunTimeHours AS HOURS_WORKED,
dbo.BomEmployee.MtdActProdHours AS PRODUCTION_HOURS,
dbo.BomEmployee.MtdNonProdHours AS STANDING_TIME_HOURS, 
dbo.BomEmployee.StdHrsPerMonth AS BUDGETED_HOURS,
CASE
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'CCOTAR' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'CCOTAR' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'CCOTWI' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'CCOTWI' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'CCOTPM' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'CCOTPM' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'CCOTLA' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'CCOTLA' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'CCOTSA' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'CCOTSA' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'CCOTSU' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'CCOTSU' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'ELOTAD' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'ELOTAD' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'ELOTCA' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'ELOTCA' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'ELOTDE' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'ELOTDE' THEN 0
   WHEN LWorkCentre = 'MAOTFA' THEN LRunTimeHours
   WHEN LWorkCentre != 'MAOTFA' THEN 0
END AS Overtime
FROM dbo.PrjJobHierDet
INNER JOIN  dbo.WipJobPost
   ON dbo.PrjJobHierDet.JobEstimate = dbo.WipJobPost.Job
INNER JOIN dbo.PrjContMaster
   ON dbo.PrjContMaster.Contract = dbo.WipJobPost.Job
INNER JOIN dbo.BomEmployee
   ON dbo.BomEmployee.Employee = dbo.WipJobPost.LEmployee
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.BomWorkCentre
   ON dbo.WipJobPost.LWorkCentre = BomWorkCentre.WorkCentre
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query, it only makes sense that there isn't any data joinable in your inner joins.

These two tables are joining on the same field, should they be?

```
 INNER JOIN  dbo.WipJobPost
    ON dbo.PrjJobHierDet.JobEstimate = dbo.WipJobPost.Job
 INNER JOIN dbo.PrjContMaster
    ON dbo.PrjContMaster.Contract = dbo.WipJobPost.Job
```

Without knowing how else your data is structured, try switching your inner joins to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to figure out why it isn't joining properly